# Граница исчезает по кругу

Tags: html, css, css3, анимация, css-animation

Как сделать последнюю часть вращающегося круга постепенно исчезающей?

```css
#loader-wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1000;
}
#loader {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    margin: -75px 0 0 -75px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 5px solid transparent;
    border-top-color: #aaa;
    border-right-color: #aaa;    
    animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}
 
@keyframes spin {
    0%   {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="loader-wrapper">
  <div id="loader"></div>
</div>
```

Я попытался использовать градиент, но он преобразует круг в квадрат.

Перевод ответа: [Border fade in circle @Cornwell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41352420/7394871)

Comment: ассоциация :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41352420/border-fade-in-circle/41352488#41352488

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Круг с фоновым градиентом, псевдоэлемент поверх и `clip-path` с SVG-фоллбеком, чтобы немного этот круг обрезать.

```css
#clip-svg {
  display: none;
}

.loader {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 200px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#999, #fff);
  position: relative;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 50% 50%, 50% 100%, 0% 100%);
  clip-path: url(#clip);
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 50% 50%, 50% 100%, 0% 100%);
  animation: spin linear 2s infinite;
}

.loader:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  border-radius: inherit;
  background-color: #fff;
}

@keyframes spin {
  to {
    transform: rotate(1turn)
  }
}
```

```html
<div class=loader></div>

<svg id=clip-avg>
  <defs>
    <clipPath id=clip clipPathUnits=objectBoundingBox>
      <polygon points="0,0 1,0 .5,.5 .5,1 0,1" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Вариант с CSS-переменными и «HTML API».

```css
#clip-svg {
  display: none;
}

.loader {
  width: calc(var(--radius, 100px) * 2);
  height: calc(var(--radius, 100px) * 2);
  border-radius: var(--radius, 100px);
  background-image: linear-gradient(#999, #fff);
  position: relative;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 50% 50%, 50% 100%, 0% 100%);
  clip-path: url(#clip);
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 50% 50%, 50% 100%, 0% 100%);
  animation: spin linear 2s infinite;
}

.loader:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  left: var(--width, 10px);
  top: var(--width, 10px);
  width: calc(var(--radius, 100px) * 2 - var(--width, 10px) * 2);
  height: calc(var(--radius, 100px) * 2 - var(--width, 10px) * 2);
  border-radius: inherit;
  background-color: #fff;
}

@keyframes spin {
  to {
    transform: rotate(1turn)
  }
}
```

```html
<div class=loader style="--radius: 150px; --width: 5px;"></div>

<svg>
  <defs>
    <clipPath id=clip clipPathUnits=objectBoundingBox>
      <polygon points="0,0 1,0 .5,.5 .5,1 0,1" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 4):

Вы можете применить градиент к псевдоэлементу следующим образом:

```css
#loader-wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
}
#loader {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: -75px 0 0 -75px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #aaa;
  border-right-color: #aaa;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}
#loader::after {
  content: '';
  width: 85%;
  height: 85%;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 40%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7) 60%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: translate(-5%, -5%);
}
@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="loader-wrapper">
  <div id="loader"></div>
</div>
```

Перевод ответа: [Border fade in circle @Ricky](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41352488/7394871)