# Как закрасить путь по линии?

Tags: css, svg

По умолчанию линия закрашивается просто как область слева направо.
А как намотать градиент на линию, чтобы начало было красным, а конец синим?

```css
html, body, svg {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
}

path {
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 3px;
  stroke: url(#gradient);
  stroke-linecap: round;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="-2 -2 36 36">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="gradient" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="red"/>
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="blue"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>

  <path d="M 16 0 a 16 16 0 1 1 0 32 a 8 8 0 1 1 0 -16" />
</svg>
```

[image: Скриншот и желаемый результат]

Comment: Навеяно вопросом https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/654874/%D0%93%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D1%83/ ? :)

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko, ага, но не только им. Я давно собирался спросить.

Comment: @Qwertiy, а его нельзя сначала раскрасить, а потом каким-нибудь трансформом свернуть?

Answer (score 2):

На просторах интернета нашелся такой пример с использованием D3.js.

**Примерный перевод:**

Этот пример демонстрирует способ создания градиента, который идет вдоль линии. Такая техника иногда используется для определения направленности вдоль искривленного края, например, [иерархического связывания краев](https://bl.ocks.org/1044242).

Для начала возьмем любой `SVG path`-элемент и равномерно разделим точки вдоль пути, используя [`getPointAtLength`](https://bl.ocks.org/1044242) (этот метод также может быть использован для [анимации](https://bl.ocks.org/3916621) `path`). Затем для каждого сегмента между соседними точками, рассчитаем [угловое соединение](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miter_joint) при помощи [`line-line intersection`](https://bl.ocks.org/1044242). И в конце заполним каждый сегмент путем интерполяции начального и конечного цветов, в данном случае от зеленого к красному, используя нормализованную длину *t* вдоль `path`. Несмотря на то, что каждый сегмент представляет собой постоянный цвет, линия состоит из множества сегментов, благодаря чему возникает эффект градиента.

В данном примере использован тонкий штрих в добавок к заполнению сегментов. Это позволяет избежать артефактов при сглаживании в большинстве современных браузеров без применения [full-scene сглаживания](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=35211).

Источник:

> https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4163057

```js
var color = d3.interpolateRainbow;

var path = d3.select("path").remove();

d3.select("svg").selectAll("path")
    .data(quads(samples(path.node(), 8)))
  .enter().append("path")
    .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.t); })
    .style("stroke", function(d) { return color(d.t); })
    .attr("d", function(d) { return lineJoin(d[0], d[1], d[2], d[3], 32); });

// Разделим SVG path равномерно с определенной точностью.
function samples(path, precision) {
  var n = path.getTotalLength(), t = [0], i = 0, dt = precision;
  while ((i += dt) < n) t.push(i);
  t.push(n);
  return t.map(function(t) {
    var p = path.getPointAtLength(t), a = [p.x, p.y];
    a.t = t / n;
    return a;
  });
}

// Рассчитаем четверки соседних точек [p0, p1, p2, p3].
function quads(points) {
  return d3.range(points.length - 1).map(function(i) {
    var a = [points[i - 1], points[i], points[i + 1], points[i + 2]];
    a.t = (points[i].t + points[i + 1].t) / 2;
    return a;
  });
}

// Рассчитаем внещний штрих для сегмента p12.
function lineJoin(p0, p1, p2, p3, width) {
  var u12 = perp(p1, p2),
      r = width / 2,
      a = [p1[0] + u12[0] * r, p1[1] + u12[1] * r],
      b = [p2[0] + u12[0] * r, p2[1] + u12[1] * r],
      c = [p2[0] - u12[0] * r, p2[1] - u12[1] * r],
      d = [p1[0] - u12[0] * r, p1[1] - u12[1] * r];

  if (p0) { // обрежем ad и dc используя среднее число от u01 и u12
    var u01 = perp(p0, p1), e = [p1[0] + u01[0] + u12[0], p1[1] + u01[1] + u12[1]];
    a = lineIntersect(p1, e, a, b);
    d = lineIntersect(p1, e, d, c);
  }

  if (p3) { // обрежем ab и dc используя среднее число от u12 и u23
    var u23 = perp(p2, p3), e = [p2[0] + u23[0] + u12[0], p2[1] + u23[1] + u12[1]];
    b = lineIntersect(p2, e, a, b);
    c = lineIntersect(p2, e, d, c);
  }

  return "M" + a + "L" + b + " " + c + " " + d + "Z";
}

// Рассчитаем пересечение двух бесконечных линий ab и cd.
function lineIntersect(a, b, c, d) {
  var x1 = c[0], x3 = a[0], x21 = d[0] - x1, x43 = b[0] - x3,
      y1 = c[1], y3 = a[1], y21 = d[1] - y1, y43 = b[1] - y3,
      ua = (x43 * (y1 - y3) - y43 * (x1 - x3)) / (y43 * x21 - x43 * y21);
  return [x1 + ua * x21, y1 + ua * y21];
}

// Вычислим единичный вектор перпендикулярный к p01.
function perp(p0, p1) {
  var u01x = p0[1] - p1[1], u01y = p1[0] - p0[0],
      u01d = Math.sqrt(u01x * u01x + u01y * u01y);
  return [u01x / u01d, u01y / u01d];
}
```

```css
html, body, svg {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
}

path {
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 3px;
  stroke-linecap: round;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>

<svg width="960" height="500">
  <path d="
      M86,388
      L203,330
      C320,272,554,156,673.8333333333334,165.83333333333334
      C793.6666666666666,175.66666666666666,799.3333333333334,311.3333333333333,683.5,316.6666666666667
      C567.6666666666666,322,330.3333333333333,197,211.66666666666666,134.5
      L93,72"></path>
</svg>
```

Comment: Во-первых, там какая-то жесть получается, а во-вторых, хотелось бы без скриптов...

Comment: Я не думаю, что без скриптов это возможно реализовать, потому что градиент накладывается всегда под определенным углом. Т. е., я имею в виду, что без скриптов и *автоматически* это нельзя сделать, так можно разбить `path` на кусочки руками и *имитировать* градиент, что, собственно, и сделано в этом примере.

Answer (score 2):

Идея разбить линию на кусочки и применить к каждому градиент уже использовалась ранее.  Ниже две половинки фигуры и у каждой свой патч, со своим  градиентом.

```
<path  id="path2" d="M 32 0 a 8 8 0 1 1 0 16" />
      <path  id="path1" d="M 32 0 a 8 8 0 1 1 0 -16" />
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     width="30" height="30"   viewBox="0 -30 60 60" >

  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="grad1" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="10%" y2="100%">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="red" stop-opacity="1"/>
      
   <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#FFE4E1" stop-opacity="1"/>
    </linearGradient>
 
 <linearGradient id="grad2" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#FFE4E1" /> 
   <stop offset="100%" stop-color="blue"/> 
      
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  
  <style>
  html, body, svg {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
}

#path1 {
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 3px;
  stroke: url(#grad1);
  stroke-linecap: round;
}

#path2 {
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 3px;
  stroke: url(#grad2);
  stroke-linecap: round;
}
  </style>
  
  <g transform="skewX(0) skewY(0)">
  <path  id="path2" d="M 32 0 a 8 8 0 1 1 0 16" />
  <path  id="path1" d="M 32 0 a 8 8 0 1 1 0 -16" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Благодарность @Grundy, за подсказку о последующем трансформировании.

Ниже пример с трансформацией - скручивания вокруг осей `X`и `Y`

```
 <g transform="skewX(40) skewY(10)">
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     width="30" height="30"   viewBox="0 -30 60 60" >

  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="grad1" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="10%" y2="100%">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="red" stop-opacity="1"/>
      
   <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#FFE4E1" stop-opacity="1"/>
    </linearGradient>
 
 <linearGradient id="grad2" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#FFE4E1" /> 
   <stop offset="100%" stop-color="blue"/> 
      
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  
  <style>
  html, body, svg {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
}

#path1 {
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 3px;
  stroke: url(#grad1);
  stroke-linecap: round;
}

#path2 {
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 3px;
  stroke: url(#grad2);
  stroke-linecap: round;
}
  </style>
  
  <g transform="skewX(40) skewY(10)">
  <path  id="path2" d="M 32 0 a 8 8 0 1 1 0 16" />
  <path  id="path1" d="M 32 0 a 8 8 0 1 1 0 -16" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

**Пример с анимцией `skewX`:**

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     width="30" height="30"   viewBox="0 -30 60 60" >

  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="grad1" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="10%" y2="100%">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="red" stop-opacity="1"/>
      
   <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#FFE4E1" stop-opacity="1"/>
    </linearGradient>
 
 <linearGradient id="grad2" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#FFE4E1" /> 
   <stop offset="100%" stop-color="blue"/> 
      
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  
  <style>
  html, body, svg {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
}

#path1 {
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 3px;
  stroke: url(#grad1);
  stroke-linecap: round;
}

#path2 {
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 3px;
  stroke: url(#grad2);
  stroke-linecap: round;
}
  </style>
  
  <g transform="skewX(0) skewY(0)">
  <path  id="path2" d="M 32 0 a 8 8 0 1 1 0 16" />
  <path  id="path1" d="M 32 0 a 8 8 0 1 1 0 -16" />
  
   <animateTransform begin="0s" attributeName="transform" type="skewX" dur="15s" repeatCount="2" values="0;60;0;-60;0" fill="freeze"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```